# How make commandButton not fully refresh page? How to use f:ajax?

Tags: jsf, refresh, commandbutton

I have a button to submit a form and invoke a managed bean action.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

But when I press the button it refreshes the whole page and sometimes also changes the URL.

Is there some way to not refresh the page and still invoke the action?

Comment: For your consideration, you may want to look at the [Primefaces PhotoCam](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/photoCam.jsf) component.  I believe it makes use of HTML5 rather than Flash though.

Comment: Primefaces PhotoCam sure looks Flash based to me (which is wise since none of the major browsers support camera access through HTML(5)/JavaScript, as far as I know only Opera currently supports it).

Comment: PF photoCam uses native access now where available

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make use of Ajax. It's a matter of nesting [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) inside the command button of interest.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...>
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Particularly the `render="@none"` (which is the default value anyway, you could just omit the attribute altogether) will instruct JSF to re-render just nothing after the submit. If you intend to re-render only a specific component instead of the whole page, then you could also specify the ID of that specific component in `render` attribute.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton ...>
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="result" />
    </h:commandButton>
    ...
    <h:panelGroup id="result">...</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

If you're already using PrimeFaces, then it's a matter of simply using `<p:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`. It uses by default ajax already, so you don't need to nest in a `<f:ajax>`. You only need to remember to use attribute names `process` and `update` instead of `execute` and `render`.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton ... update="result" />
    ...
    <h:panelGroup id="result">...</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The `execute` attribute defaults to `@form` already, so it could be omitted.

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I thought <h:commandButton ajax="true"> was default though. But it doesnt' work without ajax tag. Any idea why?

Comment: @eskalera: you're confusing standard JSF with PrimeFaces.