# How to make commandButton don't reload / refresh the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

Actually I have one input and I want to send the request without page reload (Ajax, probably). My code is bellow, but first I need to say I already see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988780/how-make-commandbutton-not-refresh-a-page) and it don't solve my problem.

**Following is my code:**

```
<h:form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="disciplina" value="#{disciplinaMBean.nome}" valueChangeListener="#{disciplinaMBean.atualizarListagemPesquisa}">
                 <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela"/>  
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-success" action="#{disciplinaMBean.cadastrar}">
                 <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

The "render" in  is to update a dataTable that I have in my page.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

**Remembering, I want:**

1. When user insert a text and click in button, send the form normally.
2. But when send the request/form, don't refresh/reload the page.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the backing-bean `@ViewScoped` ?

Comment: Why don't you wright `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />` inside of `h:commandButton` as in your question provided ?

Comment: You mean, the `<h:commandButton>` doesn't fire an ajax request, but a synchronous request as if the `<f:ajax>` wasn't been added? Are you using JSF 2.x? Do you have a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer found:

I searched in Google and I find some solutions, so I adapt the answers I find to my problem.

**Following is my lastest code:**

```
<h:form id="inserirDisciplina">
    <h:inputText id="disciplina" value="#{disciplinaMBean.nome}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" action="#{disciplinaMBean.cadastrar}">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{disciplinaMBean.cadastrar}"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

If you have the same problem, probably what you need is the tag `f:ajax` with `#{yourBean.yourMethod}` inside the `listener` attribute.