# JSF Prevent commandLink to reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I need to prevent it because I'm losing the params from the page when the button is clicked.

This is my code:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="ui-btn ui-btn-c ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right" value="Continuar" action="#{metaWEB.btnProximo()}" />
```

I found some results here, like that [How make commandButton not fully refresh page? How to use f:ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988780/how-make-commandbutton-not-refresh-a-page)

But my action use messages from the page, so it need reload the form, but the page not.

I found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868130/preventing-jsf-commandbutton-from-reloading-the-page/18868374#18868374

I think could be my solution, but I don't understand what he did :(

Thanks Advanced

Comment: Do you have any idea about AJAX ?

Comment: In addition to @BalusC' answer: your `listener` can be any method, just make sure you call it like that: `listener="#{metaWEB.btnProximo()}"` - the `()` part is important here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just make it an ajax (asynchronous) button instead of a regular (synchronous) button. It's a matter of nesting a `<f:ajax>` inside the existing tag.

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandLink>
```

The `execute="@form"` tells JSF to process the entire form (all input components enclosed in the form the command component is sitting in). The `render="@form"` tells JSF to update the entire form as ajax response (so if you display messages inside the very same form, they would be updated as well).

Don't forget to make sure that you return `null` or `void` from the button's action method, otherwise the view may still change as consequence of a non-`null`/`void` navigation outcome.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) - [Ajax (asynchronous) POST form](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxPOSTForm)

Comment: oooo thank you.
I just needed call ajax to render my message --'
You put me on the right way ^^

Comment: Thanks  dude  you saved  my  day, I was stuck for  4 hours

Answer (score 3):

Just remember to change the render="@none" to not reload the page...

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
```